# Simplemodal on Symfony Webpack

Tags: jquery, symfony, webpack

I'm trying to implement simplemodal (https://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) on my Symfony project compiling assets with Webpack.

I've downloaded and added to my 'assets' folder.

This is my webpack config:

```
.addEntry('app', [
    './assets/js/jquery.simplemodal.js',
    './assets/js/app.js',
])
```

An I have uncommented `.autoProvidejQuery()`

Then in app.js:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // Load dialog on click
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
        return false;
    });
});
```

And finally, in front:

```
<div id='basic-modal'>
        <h3>Basic Modal Dialog</h3>
        <p>A basic modal dialog with minimal styling and no additional options. There are a few CSS properties set internally by SimpleModal, however, SimpleModal relies mostly on style options and/or external CSS for the look and feel.</p>
        <input type='button' name='basic' value='Demo' class='basic'/> or <a href='#' class='basic'>Demo</a>
    </div>

    <!-- modal content -->
    <div id="basic-modal-content">
        <h3>Basic Modal Dialog</h3>
        <p>For this demo, SimpleModal is using this "hidden" data for its content. You can also populate the modal dialog with an AJAX response, standard HTML or DOM element(s).</p>
        <p>Examples:</p>
        <p><code>$('#basicModalContent').modal(); // jQuery object - this demo</code></p>
        <p><code>$.modal(document.getElementById('basicModalContent')); // DOM</code></p>
        <p><code>$.modal('&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;HTML&lt;/b&gt; elements&lt;/p&gt;'); // HTML</code></p>
        <p><code>$('&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;').load('page.html').modal(); // AJAX</code></p>

        <p><a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/'>More details...</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's simple. Buuuut, qhen clicking to open window I've this error:

```
jquery.simplemodal.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: a.parent(...).parent(...).size is not a function
at Object.init (jquery.simplemodal.js:10)
at jQuery.fn.init.b.fn.modal (jquery.simplemodal.js:9)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (app.js:11)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5237)
at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5044)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution here.

I checked some posts and the error is on `.size()` deprecated function. Replacing with `.length` works.